# .NET Core doesn't know about Windows 1252, how to fix?

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, .net-core, windows-1252

This program works just fine when compiled for .NET 4 but does not when compiled for .NET Core. I understand the error about encoding not supported but not how to fix it.

```
Public Class Program
    Public Shared Function Main(ByVal args As String()) As Integer
        System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: This is not a real fix because it changes the code in the question. But if the reason to use codepage 1252 is reading/writing characters of ISO-8859-1 then one could replace it by 28591 which is included in .NET Core without adding a CodePages package:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider?view=netcore-3.1

Be aware that some characters beyond ISO-8859-1are different in codepage 1252
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Windows-1252, especially the Euro sign (€).

Answer (score 261, accepted):

To do this, you need to [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.text.encoding#System_Text_Encoding_RegisterProvider_System_Text_EncodingProvider_) the [`CodePagesEncodingProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider) instance from the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` package.

To do that, install [the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/):

```
dotnet add package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages
```

Then (after implicitly or explicitly running `dotnet restore`) you can call:

```cs
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
var enc1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

Alternatively, if you only need that one code page, you can get it directly, without registration:

```cs
var enc1252 = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1252);
```

Comment: Where should I install or where directory should I run the `dotnet add package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`?

Comment: @Rich You should run it from the directory with your `csproj`. If you're using Visual Studio, you can also use the Package Manager instead of that command.

Comment: The above won't help with .NET Core 2.0+ for some particular Encoding properties like HeaderName. This will still throw `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: BTW: One should not use `CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding` with a variable input.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider?view=netcore-3.1 says: "you should not call the EncodingProvider.GetEncoding overloads".

Reason might be that `EncodingProvider` will not give you every encoding, but probably only additional encodings (e.g. you won't get ISO-8859-1 codepage as `CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(28591)` gives `null`).

Comment: In Azure Functions on .net 6 this line throws an exception `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.`. Seems like nobody has ever had this problem before. Any ideas?

Comment: The other (a bit longer) way is use the GetEncoding() overload by name: `Encoding encodingByName = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");`

Answer (score 17):

Please write:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

in csproj.

In package console write ' dotnet restore', restore assemblies.

and wite this code for sample:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: The NET CORE version for this question is 1.0 (as should be obvious from the date); this answer doesn't work.

Comment: I know it was the wrong version (this worked for me in 1.1, but it worked like a charm. Gracias amigo.

Comment: I think it's important to add that the static constructor won't work if your encoding is stored as a static readonly field or static const on the same class. It won't be executed in time when accessing the field. One way around this is to use a lambda property: `public static Encoding Windows1252 => Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`

Comment: @masterwok: You can't store one of these in a `const` and if you want it in a `static readonly` you can initialize it in the static constructor rather than inline.

Answer (score 4):

Here is remarks for [`CodePagesEncodingProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider):

> The .NET Framework for the Windows desktop supports a large set of Unicode and code page encodings. .NET Core, on the other hand, supports only the following encodings:
>
> - ASCII (code page 20127), which is returned by the Encoding.ASCII property.
> - ISO-8859-1 (code page 28591).
> - UTF-7 (code page 65000), which is returned by the Encoding.UTF7 property.
> - UTF-8 (code page 65001), which is returned by the Encoding.UTF8 property.
> - UTF-16 and UTF-16LE (code page 1200), which is returned by the Encoding.Unicode property.
> - UTF-16BE (code page 1201), which is instantiated by calling the UnicodeEncoding.UnicodeEncoding or UnicodeEncoding.UnicodeEncoding constructor with a bigEndian value of true.
> - UTF-32 and UTF-32LE (code page 12000), which is returned by the Encoding.UTF32 property.
> - UTF-32BE (code page 12001), which is instantiated by calling an UTF32Encoding constructor that has a bigEndian parameter and providing a value of true in the method call.

> Other than code page 20127, code page encodings are not supported.
> The `CodePagesEncodingProvider` class extends `EncodingProvider` to make these code pages available to .NET Core.

So you need to register encodings provider first to use additional encodings like `Windows-1252`.

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

[`CodePagesEncodingProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider) provides access to an encoding provider for code pages that otherwise are available only in the desktop .NET Framework.

After that you can find more encodings and can get `Windows-1252` too:

```
Encoding win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

Note that you need a reference to `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll` to use `CodePagesEncodingProvider` in some .net versions you have to add [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) to your project.

```
Install-Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages
```

Comment: Late, fat, and adds nothing to existing answers.