# Which Encoding is used by CharSet.Ansi?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Which `System.Text.Encoding` is used by `CharSet.Ansi`?

I want to decode a string in a .NET Core app (that was marshalled before by C++ code) without defining a structure and using `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(???).GetString(...)
```

In a .NET Framework application `System.Text.Encoding.Default` works:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Structure
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string FieldA;
}

public class Net461App
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var @struct = new Structure { FieldA = "äöüß" };
        byte[] buffer = ToByteArray(@struct);
        var unmarshalled = ToStructure<Structure>(buffer).FieldA;                     // "äöüß"

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0'));             // "äöüß"
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.EncodingName);                             // Western European (Windows)                    
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.CodePage);                                 // 1252

        int ansiCodePage = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage; // 1252
        Encoding ansiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(ansiCodePage);                   // works
        Console.WriteLine(ansiEncoding.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0'));                 // "äöüß"
        Console.WriteLine(ansiEncoding.EncodingName);                                 // Western European (Windows) 
        Console.WriteLine(ansiEncoding.CodePage);                                     // 1252 
    }

    public static byte[] ToByteArray<T>(T structure) where T : struct
    {
        var buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(structure)];
        IntPtr handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, handle, true);
            Marshal.Copy(handle, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            return buffer;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle);
        }

    }

    public static T ToStructure<T>(byte[] buffer) where T : struct
    {
        IntPtr handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, handle, buffer.Length);
            return Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(handle);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle);
        }

    }
}
```

`Encoding.Default` is the same as `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage` which both produce the same string as `CharSet.Ansi`. But is `TextInfo.ANSICodePage` always the same as `CharSet.Ansi`?

`Encoding.Default` is different in .NET Core and the code page 1252 is not supported:

```
public class NetCore2App
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var @struct = new Structure { FieldA = "äöüß" };
        byte[] buffer = ToByteArray(@struct);
        var unmarshalled = ToStructure<Structure>(buffer).FieldA;                     // "äöüß"

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0'));             // "????"
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.EncodingName);                             // Unicode(UTF - 8)                
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.CodePage);                                 // 65001

        int ansiCodePage = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage; // 1252
        Encoding ansiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(ansiCodePage);                   // throws "No data is available for encoding 1252."
        Console.WriteLine(ansiEncoding.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0'));                 // ...
        Console.WriteLine(ansiEncoding.EncodingName);                                 // ...
        Console.WriteLine(ansiEncoding.CodePage);                                     // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Update:**

Investigating the suggestion to use [System.Text.Encoding.CodePages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) I found the following hint about getting the systems current ANSI code page:

`Encoding.GetEncoding`

- [To get the encoding associated with the default ANSI code page in the operating system's regional and language settings, you can either supply a value 0 for the codepage argument](http://To%20get%20the%20encoding%20associated%20with%20the%20default%20ANSI%20code%20page%20in%20the%20operating%20system's%20regional%20and%20language%20settings,%20you%20can%20either%20supply%20a%20value%200%20for%20the%20codepage%20argument)
- [If the registered provider is the CodePagesEncodingProvider, the method returns the encoding that matches the system active code page when running on the Windows operating system.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.registerprovider?view=netframework-4.7.1)

The following seems to work:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
int currentAnsiCodePage = Encoding.GetEncoding(0).CodePage;
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(currentAnsiCodePage);
```

Each of the following gives me the same code page that correctly decodes the string in my test

- Encoding.GetEncoding(0).CodePage (requires `CodePagesEncodingProvider` registration)
- Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage
- CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage

Not sure which one is preferable and works an all machines.

Comment: I expect Ansi to always return the system locale codepage, i.e. 1252 for a Western European Windows, 1250 for e.g. Czech, 1251 for russian, etc.  As for 1252 being unknown, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix

Comment: But how do I get the current system local codepage programmatically? Is TextInfo.ANSICodePage the correct way?

Comment: I would expect this to be so, yes.

Comment: The thing called "ANSI" in native functions (which is, I should point out, *not* ANSI, but that misnomer's very old) is the current system code page as retrieved by [`GetACP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd318070). If writing P/Invoke code that I know to be Windows-specific, I might prefer calling to this rather than trying to figure out which piece of managed code corresponds exactly to that. If the code must be portable, I suppose all bets are off. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage` *should* be fine, but I have no idea how it's implemented on Linux.