# VS Code C# - System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1252

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, xls, exceldatareader

I am trying to use ExcelDataReader to read an .xls file on Ubuntu. I am using VS Code with C#. Here is the code:

```
var stream = File.Open(filePath, mode: FileMode.Open, access: FileAccess.Read);
var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
```

I also tried this:

```
var reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
```

When I run, I am getting the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
>      at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32 codepage)

I already installed the `libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil` (tried also with `libmono-i18n4.0-all`) as I found out some people recommending this, but the problem persists. Also installed the package `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` without success.

Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`... installed, or installed **and registered**?

Comment: Hi, @spender . If by "registered" you meant include the reference at .csproj , yes, it is also registered (`<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.4.0" />`).

Comment: So you didn't run this snippet somewhere in your code?: `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37870346/14357) suggests that this is required.

Comment: Yes, @Spender . I had put that line in my code but I think I forgot something because it did not work. After you warn in this comment, I tried again and it worked. Please put this comment as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

I faced the same problem with .net Core application. I added the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` nuget package and registered the encoding provider before `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)` which resolved the issue.

```
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
//open file and returns as Stream
using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
      using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
      {
      }
}
```

Comment: This is documented on the official page too. https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#important-note-on-net-core

Comment: Works for same error for ExecuteReader on Cache ODBC Connection