# Occasional System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1252

Tags: asp.net-core

In .NET Core 2.0 on Windows IIS, I am reading a partial html file in to a string:

```
   string sWelcomeContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(welcomepagePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

This works normally, but very rarely (it happened twice last year), I get an error:
System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1252.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 6):

Add **System.Text.Encoding.CodePages** NuGet package to solution and use the following piece of code in application startup class to registester new encodings.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

    // more code here
}
```

Comment: http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/10/no-data-is-available-for-encoding/
**or**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215791/vs-code-c-sharp-system-notsupportedexception-no-data-is-available-for-encodin

Comment: Not sure this addresses the issue of the OP. OP clearly states that the above code is working in general just in rare occasions it fails