# windows-1251 encoding on C# mono project under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu, encoding, windows-1251

my difficult life force me to use "windows-1251" encoding on C# under Ubuntu 16.04. I use "mono" to run C#.

both commands

```
 Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)
 Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")
```

give this exception

```
System.NotSupportedException: Encoding 1251 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled.
  at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (System.Int32 codepage) [0x0023f] in <65984520577646ec9044386ec4a7b3dd>:0
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33579717/7092462), I need to use

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

but my c# can't find "RegisterProvider". **As far a I understood**, I need to include "System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" manually.
Some steps are described [here in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215791/vs-code-c-sharp-system-notsupportedexception-no-data-is-available-for-encodin), but I can't understand where can I download it and how can I  link it.

Could someone advice me how to include it (if it solves the problem) or tell me what to do in general.

Comment: Try to install "mono-locale-extras" package

Comment: If you check the comments there's a link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix/37870346#37870346) that explains all the steps for *.NET Core*