# Cannot write files in Windows-1252 encoding, get UTF-8 instead

Tags: c#, character-encoding, visual-studio-2017, windows-1252

This is driving me insane. I want to read a number of text files (located outside my project directory), encoded with Windows-1252, edit them as strings, and write back to those files, again as Windows-1252. Yet Visual Studio keeps churning out UTF-8 files instead.

Here's my file reading code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.Default))
{
    String s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return s;
}
```

Here is my file writing code:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, joinedFileString, Encoding.Default);
```

In between these two I perform various edits, including adding, removing, and grepping linebreaks, but I presumed that those would be resolved in the proper encoding by specifying the encoding in File.WriteAllText. Note that I have, in the Advanced Save Options of Visual Studio, changed the default encoding to 1252. So Encoding.Default should refer to the proper one.

Yet it keeps turning files into UTF-8! :-(

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `Encoding.Default` to target a specific encoding. I don't think the Visual Studio settings would affect this, while system settings would. Does `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` work in it's place?

Comment: @JonathonChase Thanks, but I tried that. I get ``"No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method."``

Comment: You may want to look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215791/vs-code-c-sharp-system-notsupportedexception-no-data-is-available-for-encodin) regarding the encoding error you receive.

Comment: ...that actually worked. I cannot believe it.

Comment: Do you want to put it as an answer, so I can Accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to specify the encoding you are using more explicitly. `Encoding.Default` may vary from system to system, and [according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx),

> the default encoding can even change on a single computer.

Since you know which encoding you want, you can specify it specifically with `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`

In some environments, you may need to register a provider for the available encodings. You can do this by adding the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` nuget package to your project and registering it with `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);`