# How to mock ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader and return IExcelDataReader data

Tags: .net-core, moq, azure-blob-storage, xunit

I am using xUnit and Moq for writing unit tests.

My **ExcelData** class has below code

```
       public DataTable ReadFromExcel(CloudBlockBlob MasterDataSourceBlob, string SheetName)
        {
            DataTable dataInExcelSheet = new DataTable();
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                MasterDataSourceBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
                var headers = new List<string>();
               IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(memoryStream);
          }
```

Inorder to mock `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader()` , I created new class and Interface as below and returned **IExcelDataReader** .

**ExcelDataMock.cs** file has below code

```
   public  class ExcelDataMock
    {

        public IExcelDataReader CreateReader(MemoryStream memoryStream)
        {
           return ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(memoryStream); 
        }
    }
```

**IExcelDataMock.cs** file has below code

```
   public interface IExcelDataMock
    {
        IExcelDataReader CreateReader(MemoryStream memoryStream);
    }
```

My Test class has below code

```
      [Fact]
        public void ReadFromExcel_Success()
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write("sample data");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            var mockExcelDataMock = new Mock<IExcelDataMock>();
            mockExcelDataMock.Setup(data => data.CreateReader(It.IsAny<MemoryStream>())).Returns<IExcelDataReader>(
                excel =>
            {

                var item = new Mock<IExcelDataReader>();

                return item.Object;
            }
            );


            var mockCloudBlockBlob = new Mock<CloudBlockBlob>(new Uri("https://samplestorage.blob.core.windows.net/samplecontainer"));


            mockCloudBlockBlob.Setup(blob => blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>()))
                .Callback((Stream target) => stream.CopyTo(target)) 
                .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);


            string SheetName = null;

            this._iExcelOperations = new ExcelData(mockExcelDataMock.Object);

            this._iExcelOperations.ReadFromExcel(mockCloudBlockBlob.Object, SheetName);

        }
```

[image]

If I use `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(memoryStream)` I got below error

> No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a
>   custom encoding, see the documentation for the
>   Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'

If I use `this._iExcelOperationsMock.CreateReader(memoryStream)` I got error as below

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream'
>   cannot be converted to type 'ExcelDataReader.IExcelDataReader'.'

[image]

How to resolve this issue.

**Update 1:**

Error:

> invalid file signature

[image]

Comment: We are going to need a better view of the code you are showing. the current snippets are too disjointed to get a full understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: Actually I am unable to mock ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(memoryStream) . It is throwing given error. Kindly suggest resolution.

Comment: The sample code you have provided is not complete so it would make it difficult to provide a proper solution with incomplete information. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem

Comment: I also observed that you are calling `MasterDataSourceBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);` in a synchronous method, which will cause problems

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Issue has been resolved after adding System.Text.Encoding.CodePages as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215791/vs-code-c-sharp-system-notsupportedexception-no-data-is-available-for-encodin .Now I am getting different Issue which I have  specified in Update 1 in question.

Comment: @chandrasekhar Do you still have the issue mentioned in your update.