# .NET Core calls to Encoding.GetEncoding() hang

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm calling the lines below. The calls hang infinitely.

```cs
Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
```

I'm using:

- VS 2017 15.7.2
- dotnet --version > "2.1.201"
- Windows 10

Comment: They don't. People would have noticed if they did, this is a *very* porpular method. Why do you assume the application hangs there? Did you try debugging? Did you *pause* the application during debugging and check where the problem is? What does the rest of your code do?

Comment: Do you mean that they *throw* perhaps, and your application doesn't handle that properly? Do you have a `catch {}` somewhere?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1252](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858209/system-notsupportedexception-no-data-is-available-for-encoding-1252)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method doesn't block. Most likely it throws and the rest of the code handles the exception in a way that makes it seem like the code is blocking. Perhaps there's a `catch {}` somewhere

From the .NET Core notes in [Character Encodings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding#platform-notes-includenetcoreincludesnet-core-mdmd)

> By default, .NET Core does not make available any code page encodings other than code page 28591 and the Unicode encodings, such as UTF-8 and UTF-16. However, you can add the code page encodings found in standard Windows apps that target .NET to your app. For complete information, see the [CodePagesEncodingProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider?view=netcore-2.0) topic.

That's *not* so strange since .NET and Windows use UTF16 already and almost all web sites, REST APIs, files use UTF8.

If you try a simple console application :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var enc=Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
    Console.WriteLine(enc);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

You'll get an exception :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1251. 
For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the 
Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32 codepage)
   at encodingtest.Program.Main(String[] args) in H:\Projects\encodingtest\Program.cs:line 11
```

You can install additional codepages by adding the [System.Text.Encoding.CodePages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) package and registering it :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
   var enc=Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
   Console.WriteLine(enc);
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

This time the application won't throw.