# Firefox opening wrong profile with selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using selenium 3.14 with geckodriver 0.24, I'm using following code to run the existing profiles I have already created for my different accounts.

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.Proxy = pro; //my proxy object
firefoxOptions.AddArgument("-profile " + path); //path to the profile
FirefoxDriverService ffDriverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
ffDriverService.BrowserCommunicationPort = 2828;
PropertiesCollection.Driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffDriverService, firefoxOptions);
```

I have multiple profiles each with a different proxy. Right now, the browser is started and everything works very well for the first profile, but once I dispose the browser and start a new one with new profile and proxy, the driver opens the same last browser. I've tried many solutions and have changed selenium to old versions but no luck.

One thing I noticed in the console is that when driver opens the browser, it runs a command on console like this:

```
1561625708285   mozrunner::runner  INFO Running command: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile C:\\Users\\Usr\\Desktop\\fprofiles\\pf1" "-foreground" "-no-remote"
```

if I run this command from cmd the profile issue remains there:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile C:\\Users\\Usr\\Desktop\\fprofiles\\pf1" "-foreground" "-no-remote"
```

If I remove the " from command and make it complete text it will look like this

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" -marionette -profile C:\\Users\\Usr\\Desktop\\fprofiles\\pf1 -foreground -no-remote
```

I cloned the selenium project of OpenQA and tried to debug there but that also uses geckodriver.exe and I guess geckodriver.exe is responsible for getting arguments and passing to firefox. 
Last but the least option will be to compile geckodriver(which has been [developed in RUST](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Building.html)) once again as per my consent but the programming language is **RUST** and that's going to be a long long job for achieving what I need.
Has anyone faced the same problem? How can I get it fixed?

Comment: For a C# version, especially for .Net Core, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629542/selenium-geckodriver-executes-findelement-10-times-slower-than-chromedriver-ne/62904948#62904948

Answer (score 0):

Try loading browser profile based on it's name. An example with profile called 'selenium_profile':

```
public static WebDriver driver;

public static String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\selenium-tests\\FF_driver_0_23\\geckodriver.exe";

public static WebDriver startFF() {
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
    FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
    options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
}
```

It must not be static so you can parse name of desired profile in argument.

Comment: For .Net Core C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629542/selenium-geckodriver-executes-findelement-10-times-slower-than-chromedriver-ne/62904948#62904948