# FirefoxWebdriver No data is available for encoding 437

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to create a FirefoxWebdriver but get the following error

```
  Message: 
    Initialization method Sma.Ldx.Systemtest.Ui.Tests.IbaTest.TestInitialize
 threw exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'System.IO.Compression.ZipStorer' threw an exception. ---> 
System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 437. For 
information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the 
Encoding.RegisterProvider method..
```

it is a netstandard2.0 lib and runs on dotnet core 2.2
Can anybody help?

I tried to import System.Text.Encoding.CodePages and try to use System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance) but this is not supported in dotnetcore2.2

```cs
private static IWebDriver InitializeFirefoxDriver(bool headless, bool remote, Uri seleniumHubUri, PlatformType platform, string locale, string webDriverPath)
        {
            var options = new FirefoxOptions()
            {
                Profile = new FirefoxProfile()
                {
                    AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true,
                    AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = true
                },
            };
            options.AddArgument($"--lang={locale}");
            if (headless || remote)
            {
                options.AddArgument("-headless");
            }
            options.PlatformName = platform.ToString();
            FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(webDriverPath, "geckodriver.exe");
            service.Start();
            return remote ? new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumHubUri, options) : new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
        }
```

I except the Firefox Browser to start but get an encoding error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add NuGet Package `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`

Before Creating the `FirefoxDriver` object, do this:

```
 CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(437);
 Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me. Out of curiosity, do you know why this fixes it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: It works because linux doesn't have that Windows encoding so when you run the remote browser some actions require Windows encodings. Once this Code Page is available linux can use that encoding.

Comment: .NET Core does not support most of encoding types by default, when .Net Framework does. So applications that were converted sometimes misses encoding that was included in .NET framework.

Comment: Thanks - solved my problem! I did a bit more research and it turns out zip files need encoding 437, which comes from the original IMB PC days  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), even on Windows. Insert the above code in some static constructor that runs before you need ZipStorer and life will be happy. (note: you cannot insert it in ZipStorer's static constructor - been there, tried that - .net can't even load ZipStorer's static constructor without this code running beforehand)

Comment: This worked for me to fix a log4net ColoredConsoleAppender error.

Answer (score 1):

One option to resolve this is to  upgrade the `Selenium.WebDriver` package to 4.*.

Context: This is an instance of this GitHub issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4816. This issue has been fixed in the 4.x branch, as the dependency that is causing this issue [has been removed](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/8480b8e7236ef9d86af0a65c9569e2451a162419/dotnet/CHANGELOG#L472-L474) in that version.