# C# | How to display Excel sheets on DataGrindView?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I'm trying to display the Excel sheet on DataGrindView. I found a solution on internet but I'm getting an error when I tried to browse the Excel file. Would anyone help me on this topic?

Browse button codes are stated below:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel 97-2003 Workbook|*.xls|Excel Workbook|*.xlsx" })
            {
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    txtFilename.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                        {
                            DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                            {
                                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() { UseHeaderRow = true }
                            });
                            tableCollection = result.Tables;
                            cboxSheet.Items.Clear();
                            foreach (DataTable table in tableCollection)
                                cboxSheet.Items.Add(table.TableName);//add sheet to combobox
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**

Hello again,

This's my first time posting something on Stackoverflow so sorry for my mistakes.

I'm going to explain more detailed about the project and the error.

[This's my Form Application format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrIJr.png)

And here's the Form code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using ExcelDataReader;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace emailsender
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void cboxSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView1.DataMember = cboxSheet.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel 97-2003 Workbook|*.xls|Excel Workbook|*.xlsx" })
            {
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    txtFilename.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                        {
                            DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                            {
                                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() { UseHeaderRow = true }
                            });
                            //tableCollection = result.Tables;
                            cboxSheet.Items.Clear();
                            foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
                                cboxSheet.Items.Add(table.TableName);//add sheet to combobox
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
                            cboxSheet.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried [@JohnG's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6842716/johng) sample but when I select the file with the file explorer and press the open button I get the same error.

[System.NotSupportedException: 'No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvdCH.png)

I cannot quite grasp the point I missed...

Comment: This was asked before, can you see if this works for you? [import-excel-to-datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293643/import-excel-to-datagridview)

Comment: Not working for me..

Comment: You say it's not working, can you explain what's not working exactly ?

Comment: I edited the post and tried to explain the problem in more detail. Sorry for the bad explanation ..

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It appears your application is a ".Net" application which uses a different encoding.

Comment: With your last edit, you have solved the problem on the project. I really do not know how much to thank. As you said, there was no problem with the code, I just used the wrong type of Form Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear... The title states you want to *”display Excel sheets on DataGridView”* … and this is certainly doable, however, I do not see anywhere in the code that attempts to set a `DataGridView` to one of the Excel worksheets. The posted code does indeed successfully read a selected Excel file into a `DataSet.` Then the code adds each worksheet name as an item into a combo box `cboxSheet.`

This all appears to work. So given your question, I will assume there is a `DataGridView` on the same `Form` that contains the `ComboBox` filled by the posted code. I assume you want the user to be able to select a particular worksheet from the combo box, then have that worksheet displayed in the `DataGridView.` If this is what you want, then fortunately, you have most of the hard work done… i.e., creating a `DataSet` where each `DataTable` in the `DataSet` is one of the worksheets from the selected Excel file.

Assuming there is a `DataGridView` on the `Form`, the code needs to set it’s `DataSource` after the code has read the Excel file. Fortunately, the code is creating a `DataSet` called `result` that we can use as a `DataSource` to the grid. Something like…

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

This will set the grid’s `DataSource` as a `DataSet.` In order to display a particular `DataTable` from the `DataSet`, the code needs to set the grids `DataMember` property to the name of the `DataTable` we want to display... and fortunately, we have all those names conveniently stored in the combo box.

Therefore, after the code sets the grid’s `DataSource`, we could also set the combo box selection to the first table in the data set and then set the grid’s `DisplayMamber` to display the selected worksheet in the gird… OR… since we know we want the grid to display a different table when the user changes a selection in the combo box, we are going to have to “wire up/subscribe" to the `ComboBoxes` `SelectedIndexChanged` event anyway.

So, after the grids data source is set, if we simply set the combo boxes selected item to the first item in the combo box, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event should take care of the rest. The combo boxes `SelectedIndexChanged` event would only need one line of code to change the grids displayed table. It may look something like…

```
private void cboxSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.DataMember = cboxSheet.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

With the combo boxes `SelectedIndexChanged` event wired up, then your current code only needs to add the two lines as shown below. Note I removed the `tableCollection` as it is not needed.

```
private void ReadExcelFileFillCombo() {
  using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel 97-2003 Workbook|*.xls|Excel Workbook|*.xlsx" }) {
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      txtFilename.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
      using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)) {
          DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() {
            ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() { UseHeaderRow = true }
          });
          //tableCollection = result.Tables;
          cboxSheet.Items.Clear();
          foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
            cboxSheet.Items.Add(table.TableName);//add sheet to combobox
          dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
          cboxSheet.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

***Edit per OP update and comments***

I can only guess the reason you are getting the error you are showing is because you are “creating” the wrong “type” of application. I will assume that your current application was created using the .Net “Core” application. From my understanding, the .Net Core uses a different “encoding” which is causing the error you see. I suggest you take a look at the SO question….

[System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1252](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858209/system-notsupportedexception-no-data-is-available-for-encoding-1252/50875725#50875725)

If you want to use a .Net Core application then you may want to follow the suggestions in the above answer. However, if you create a “.Net Framework” instead of a “.Net” application, I am confident this will solve the problem. Below is a picture of the proper application you need to get the code to work. Note… Red is not what you want, the green… “.Net Framework” is what you want to use.

[image]