# Issue reading carriage return using FileStream

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filestream

I'm having an issue in a Windows Forms VB.NET program when reading a carriage return, but only after the second read.

I've created an entire new project to focus only on the part that makes the program freeze and it's the same behavior.

It's fairly easy to recreate on your side (or not if it's related to my setup...).

- Create a new Windows Forms VB.NET (6.0) project
- Add a TextBox and make it Multiline
- Add a button and paste the code below under the method that handles the click
- Create a "first.txt" file in bin\Debug with one letter, a carriage return and another letter

File example :

```
A
B
```

Related code :

```
Using fichier As FileStream = New FileStream("first.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    If fichier.CanRead() Then
        Dim contenu(100) As Byte

        fichier.Position = 0

        fichier.Read(contenu, 0, 100)

        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty

        Try
            For Each lettre As Byte In contenu
                TextBox1.Text += Chr(lettre)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
End Using
```

First click on the button works, you get what's below in the TextBox :

`"A" & vbCrLf & "B"`

Second click on the button will make the program freeze.
When I execute step-by-step it happens when `Chr(13)` is being added to `TextBox1.Text`.
No exception risen.

I'm following a training PDF from 2013 got from a website because I wasn't able to find better.
So I'm pretty sure there is a better way to read from a file and that's not what I'm interested in here.

I'd really like to understand what's happening with that code. Especially since it works well the first time.

I couldn't find a similar post and I'm not good enough with Diagnostic tools to figure it out on my own.

Thanks for your help,

L

Comment: I appreciate the example to lead us to reproduce, but I can't reproduce. I am using .NET core and had to include this line: `System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074654/832052) but I am not sure it's related

Comment: Also, this is the correct way to append to a string: `TextBox1.Text &= Chr(lettre)`

Comment: If you comment out the Try..Catch parts, does it complain? Having an empty Catch prevents it from telling you if something has gone wrong.

Comment: If it won't tell you what is wrong, then `Dim dataLen = fichier.Read(contenu, 0, 100)` and use an ordinary For loop instead of a For Each, with something like `For i = 0 To dataLen - 1` `TextBox1.AppendText(Chr(contenu(i))`... in case the zero bytes are upsetting it.

Comment: @djv If I understood correctly .NET 6.0 is NET Core. They just got rid of the "Core" word when version 5.0 was released.
I tried to call the instruction you shared in the Form Load event but it didn't changed the behavior.
Also changed the code to `TextBox1.Text &= Chr(lettre)`, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried and program doesn't complain. Since I was testing in debugging mode I guess it would have broke execution even though the catch is empty, no ?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Also coded what you proposed with the `For ... To` loop. It doesn't solve the problem but is does optimize the algorithm. Cheers.

Comment: @Loy If you create a string from the characters instead of adding them one at a time, and then, after the loop, append that string to the TextBox, does it work? Also, exactly what is the nature of the freeze, for example if you move the window around does it fail to update its contents?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It was frozen as totally unresponsive, high CPU usage and memory consumption increasing by tiny amounts and reaching several GB (until I couldn't dare to keep it going xD). But if I use the past tense it's because you solved it ! That's well thought. Thanks mate. I think it's fair that you post it as an answer. Would you mind?

Comment: @Loy It seems to me that there is something else going wrong, so the workaround I suggested wouldn't be a real answer. I would say to do `Dim contenu = File.ReadAllText("first.txt")` `TextBox1.Text = contenu` instead of all the code you're currently using, but you said you didn't want a better way of reading the file. You're welcome to post your own answer if you want: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Don't get me wrong, I knew that this method was rubbish but wanted to correct the issue. Only for sport. For a proper dev I'll use `File.ReadAllText()`. Well I thought it would be nice to reward your efforts but you don't seem to be interested in reaching 25,000 points and unlock site analytics at the moment :-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a control as if it was a variable can cause performance problems if its properties are being changed rapidly - for example, just changing one character in its .Text property means that it needs to be re-rendered.

Instead, it is better to do the intensive work separately and then do just one change to the control, so, for the code in the question, rather than:

```
For Each lettre As Byte In contenu
    TextBox1.Text += Chr(lettre)
Next
```

you might do:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
For Each b In contenu
    sb.Append(Chr(b))
Next

TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) is usually better than concatenating a string when there are more than maybe 6–10 items to concatenate.