# asp.net-core, use a specific encoding name

Tags: asp.net-core

I need use a specific encoding name. In `asp.net` I used to do it like this:

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
var name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ישראל" ,enc)
```

How can I achieve the same in `asp.net-core`?  I was trying to use:

```
WebUtility.HtmlEncode()
```

but it does not accept the encoding name in its signature.

Comment: I can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method with the latest version of asp.net core (2.1.0).

Comment: But you cannot specify the encding name.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

1. Install [the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/):

   ```
   dotnet add package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages
   ```
2. After `dotnet restore`, use

   ```
   var enc = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1255);
   var name = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ישראל", enc);
   ```

Adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37870346/815938).