# ASP.NET Core HtmlAgilityPack Encoding errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

There are some posts regarding encoding questions and `HtmlAgilityPack` but this issue wasn't addressed:

Because the website I try to parse contains Unicode symbols like `€` or `ä`, `ü` I tried to set the encoding to Unicode:

```
public class WebpageDeserializer
{
    public WebpageDeserializer() {}

    /*
     * Example address: https://www.dslr-forum.de/showthread.php?t=1930368
    */
    public static void Deserialize(string address)
    {
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        var htmlDoc = web.Load(address);
        //further decoding fails because unicode decoded characters are not proper html (looks more like chinese)
    }
}
```

But now

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml
```

looks like this:

> ℼ佄呃偙⁅瑨汭倠䉕䥌⁃ⴢ⼯㍗⽃䐯䑔堠呈䱍ㄠ〮吠慲獮瑩潩慮⽬䔯≎...

If I try to use `UTF-8` or `iso-8859-1` the `€` symbol is converted to `�` (as well as `ä`, `ö`, `ü`). How can I fix this?

Comment: I updated my code example - I hope it contains everything you need. If not - please don't hesitate to ask for more information.

Comment: I try to reproduce the problem and LinqPad is freezing...

Comment: @FalcoAlexander than use other tools. Why do you think we should be interested in the tools you are using.

Comment: that tool is only hosting .NET! do you have any more clever ideas for the solution of the problem?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Yes, I use Visual studio and write codes to test the questions :)

Comment: also tested with RoslynPad and can reproduce the strange behaviour with huge "chinese" response that freezes the .NET host

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Strange behaviour is *correct*. but freezing is your problem. I don't have such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is mis-configured and the real encoding is **cp1252**.

Below code should work:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var buf = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://www.dslr-forum.de/showthread.php?t=1930368");
var html = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(buf);
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);` gives me a `System.NotSupportedException`. Do I have to configure something to get this encoding? I am using `.NET Core 2.1` and `Windows 10 64-bit`.
Edit: This fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix  `Thanks alot!`

Answer (score 0):

instead `Encoding.Unicode` use:

```
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
```

(tested with your website and german umlauts)

to get the right encoding check the header of the target website.
it contains the right hint:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because the `€` sign or `ä` `ü` are just removed.