# Writing text file how to force ANSI format C#

Tags: c#, text, character-encoding

Using the following to try to write a text file in ANSI but still show UTF-8 when opened.  How to write in ANSI format?  This is on Windows 10.  In notepad++ or notepad bottom right corner it will say ANSI or UTF-8 when I open different text files. The one my program produce says UTF-8.

```
private void createHeader()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string delimiter = "ª";

            sb.Append(batchNumber);
            sb.Append(delimiter);
            sb.Append("Delete PLUs");
            sb.Append(delimiter);

            string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
            //Console.WriteLine(today);
            sb.Append(today);

            for (int i =0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(delimiter);
            }

            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

            System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
            objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.ASCII);
            objWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            objWriter.Close();
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathToFile, sb.ToString(), Encoding.ASCII); // Erases current file and overwrite

            //return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: First, you are writing ASCII, not ANSi, which should result in that your delimiter should be replaced by a question mark because it’s not part of the ASCII character set. For ANSI use `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` for the most common ANSI encoding. Second, where is it shown as UTF-8? As UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII it would be understandable that applications would show the encoding as UTF-8 if you open an ASCII file.

Comment: ANSI is an Organization based in the United States. What kind of encoding are you actually trying to use? Your Local Encoding? Windows 1252? Generic Latin-1? ASCII (UTF-8 encodes the same CodePoints, since it's compatible, not by chance)?

Comment: What do you mean by "still show UTF-8 when opened"? Opened how?

Comment: In notepad++ or notepad bottom right corner it will say ANSI or UTF-8 when I open different text files.  The one my program produce says UTF-8.

Comment: ANSI is a generic name that was adopted by Microsoft a long time ago. It doesn't mean anything, per se; it's still used (because it somehow *stuck*) to define a generic text encoding, when the actual encoding is not known, it's Windows 1252 or the old `iso-8859-1` (deprecated) or when the local encoding is used (`Encoding.Default`), which uses extended character specific to the local language. If you don't have a very specific requirement for this, then use UTF-8, which is universally understood. Local Encoding can usually be interpreted only locally and produces garbage when read elsewhere.

Comment: I am trying to create a file for a process and I noticed that an exact same looking file in ANSI works but UTF-8 gets rejected by the process.

Comment: Then that Process, probably / possibly, uses the local encoding (the CodePage defined in the System configuration) to read a file. As mentioned, try using `Encoding.Default`. -- You can use `File.WriteAllText()`, you don't need two Streams (and you're not disposing of any of these) to save a piece of text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use encoding 1252.

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(pathToFile, true, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
{
          tw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: 'No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'

Comment: Does not work "out of the box" for .Net Core and .Net 5 (not sure about 6 7 8). Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix