# How to fill DataGridView by xml "Windows -1252" encode file c# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, encoding, windows-1252

I want to fill the datagridview from a XML file which is encoded as Windows-1252. I'm using .NET Core that does not support this encoding

Comment: `var enc1252 = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1252);`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37870346/724039

Comment: Xml is UTF-8.  I think you need to understand what encoding actually is.  Characters 0x00 to 0x7F are the same in all encoding schemes.  Character 0x80 to 0xFF are mapped to different unicode characters (two bytes) depending on encoding.  So encoding really allow you to save size of files so instead of using two bytes for a character you only need one byte.  So your issue is not Xml.  You want the DGV to display the bytes (0x00 to 0xFF) using a different encoding scheme.  Not the XML using different encoding.

Comment: Looks like best way is to convert the Xml UTF-8 to bytes and then change the bytes to win 1252.  See sample code : https://codesnippets.fesslersoft.de/how-to-change-the-encoding-of-a-string-using-c-and-vb-net/