# How can I override default encoding when marshalling strings?

Tags: c#, string, delphi, encoding, marshalling

I have a Delphi 2007 DLL with this export:

```pascal
function TestSignString(s, Sign: PChar): LongBool; stdcall;
```

I am calling it in .NET Core v7 C# using this import:

```cs
[DllImport(@"LibraryName.dll")]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool TestSignString(string s, string sign);
```

I am passing `s` and `sign` params, when the run-time system has default encoding (EXPECTED) WIN1250 everything goes fine as expected, however when it's not, there's default system encoding involved and passed chars are encoded using default encoding (for example to WIN1252).

So my question is, how to override default encoding when marshaling strings in C#? I mean both ways - as a input params and output as well, please.

I have tried altering the import to:

```cs
[DllImport(@"LockBoxLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
```

but no luck, I am missing code page (1250) specification.

Comment: Are you missing? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084

Comment: @RandRandom, thank you for your reply, but this question is not the case, it's about un/availability of custom encoding in .NET Core.

Comment: and you claimed `I am missing code page (1250) specification.`, `using default encoding (for example to WIN1252).` and you are using `.NET Core v7` which by default has no support for the code page you mentioned

Comment: You cannot do this ... but you can always send byte array (`ref byte[] s, ....`) instead of string and do the encoding by yourself

Comment: @RandRandom, as I wrote, this is not an issue, I have registered custom encoding and it's working fine even in .NET Core, the problem is how to override default encoding.

Comment: @Selvin, thank you, yes, this is what I whould like to do :-) Can you post a short code snipper, please?

Comment: Have you tried `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`?

Comment: @shingo, yes, no success.

Comment: @shingo `CharSet.Unicode` will marshal the strings as UTF-16, which is compatible with `PWideChar` in Delphi. But in Delphi 2007 and earlier, `PChar` maps to `PAnsiChar` instead, so is not compatible with UTF-16. `CharSet.Ansi` or `byte[]` must be used in this situation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for your expert insight. Can you post your solution, please?

Comment: @J.Ogurek You have already been told what to do - pass in `string`s and use `CharSet.Ansi` in the `DllImport`, or else pass in (null-terminated) `byte[]` arrays instead of `string`s. You could try using `PtrInt` with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`, but that's pretty heavy-handed for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

I have a "dirty" solution as it's probably memory leaking. Let me know if you know better way, please. I have two extension methods for string conversion to nint and vice versa.

```
private static string FromAnsiPtrToUtf8Str(this nint n)
{
    var length = 0;

    while (Marshal.ReadByte(n + length) != 0)
    {
        length++;
    }

    var strbuf = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(n, strbuf, 0, length);
    
    return Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetString(strbuf);
}

private static nint FromUtf8StrToAnsiPtr(this string s) => GCHandle.Alloc(Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetBytes(s), GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Import changed to: `private static extern bool TestSignString(nint s, nint sign);`

Method call: `TestSignString(s.FromUtf8StrToAnsiPtr(), sign.FromUtf8StrToAnsiPtr());`

Comment: Naming your functions `Utf8` is misleading since there is no UTF-8 involved in this code. C# strings are not UTF-8. `FromAnsiPtrToStr()` and `FromStrToAnsiPtr()` would be more accurate. But then, you are really kind of just duplicating what `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` and `Marshal.StringToXXXAnsi()` already do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, `Utf8` is not involved? I thought Utf8 is default string encoding in .NET. And duplicating `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()`? When I decompile these methods, they do different stuff - no encoding conversion like I do. Can you post your code snippet, please?

Comment: "*I thought Utf8 is default string encoding in .NET.*" - Nope, the [`String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string) type in .NET "*Represents text as a sequence of **UTF-16** code units.*" Just like everything else Unicode-related in Windows

Comment: If you look at the actual source code for `PtrToStringAnsi()`, it just calls the `sbyte*` constructor of `String`. And the doc for that constructor says the bytes "*are interpreted using the current system code page encoding (that is, the encoding specified by `Encoding.Default`).*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau, your statement is clear, however take a look at the Encoding sample... https://dotnetfiddle.net/nT8Jto

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, this is it. I am interested in overriding the default encoding as the title of this thread states.

Comment: You can't override what codepage `Encoding.Default` or `Charset.Ansi` refer to. If you need a specific encoding, use `Encoding.GetEncoding()` instead. If .NET Core doesn't support what you need, then implement the charset manually, or use a 3rd party library.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you think WIN1250 encoding is not supported in .NET Core? It is supported, the only step is to register encoding provider like this `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);`

Comment: "*you think WIN1250 encoding is not supported in .NET Core?*" - I didn't say anything about that. You did: "*I am missing code page (1250) specification*", to which RandRandom [replied to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76379702/76381932#comment134685060_76379702): "*you are using .NET Core v7 which by default has no support for the code page you mentioned*"

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `TestSignString` to take a UTF-16 string, or introduce a widestring (W) version, it is 2023 :-)

```
function TestSignStringW(s, Sign: PWideChar): LongBool; stdcall;
```

Comment: thank you for your kind help, but I am not able to change Delphi library side, that's why the topic is "How can I override default encoding when marshalling strings?"