How to properly read Czech characters from CSV file in C#?
For my C# WPF application I need to import CSV file (separated by ;). There are many different columns in CSV file (some of them are even empty). The first and second column contains the name and surname that consists of different characters - some of them from Czech alphabet (like ščřěžýáíé or ŠČŘĚŽÝÁÍÉ).
I need to correctly parse this name and surname into my application.
Can you please help me?
This is an example of CSV file:
"name";"surname" "Adam";"Veselý" "David";"Řehořčík"
I tried many different approaches to this. Maybe there is a library that can do this? I already tried CsvHelper package to parse CSV file, but I couldnt get it to work - instead of the diacritics characters it puts � character. I tried to change encoding to UTF8 using "Encoding("UTF8")" but nothing changed.
This is my final version of the function that I tried using:
public void ImportStudentsFromCsv(object obj)
{
    // Open file dialog to select CSV file
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv";
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    openFileDialog.Title = "Select CSV file";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

        try
        {
            // Configure CsvHelper to handle semicolon delimiter and diacritics
            var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Delimiter = ";",
                HasHeaderRecord = true, // Assume CSV has header
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                BadDataFound = null // Ignore bad data
            };

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
            {
                // Read CSV records into Student objects
                var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();

                // Initialize the students list
                _students = new List<Student>();

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    // Map CSV values to Student properties
                    var student = new Student
                    {
                        StudentName = record.jmeno,
                        StudentSurname = record.prijmeni,
                        StudentProgram = record.oborKomb,
                        StudentYear = Convert.ToInt32(record.rocnik),
                        ClassId = SelectedClass.Id,
                        Card = "card not assigned"
                    };

                    // Add student to the list
                    _students.Add(student);
                }
            }

            // Save students to the database
            using (var db = new UserContext())
            {
                db.student.AddRange(_students);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Update the UI
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Students));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error occurred while importing students: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}


I installed the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages NuGet package, tried to follow the step of this answer. Cannot get it to work with Windows-1250 encoding, like it does not recognise Windows-1250 or Windows-1252 encodings.

What encoding is the file? Apparently it’s not utf8

If you see � it means the file is not UTF8. The character � is an error character used when trying to read text with the wrong encoding. The easy solution would be to tell whoever produced this to use UTF8 instead. Otherwise you'll have to find the correct encoding and use it instead. This doesn't require any libraries. it does not recognise Windows-1250 or Windows-1252 encodings. are you running on Linux? Try Encoding.GetEncoding(1250), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) or Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2")etc

BTW only put the encoding in StreamReader. That's the class that actually reads the bytes and converts them to text. This reduces the chances of using one codepage in one place and a different one in another

Thank you, I already fixed it with the help of this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix . Cannot put the answer here tho, because the thread is closed :(

@yanni that makes your question a duplicate. You didn't say you're targeting .NET Core.


Encoding.UTF8

Your file probably just isn't UTF-8. Maybe it's Windows-1250. Without seeing the file, I'm afraid there is no way to tell. I'd just try Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1250") instead of UTF-8 and see if it works.

More a comment than an answer (and the -1 is not me)

Thank you for your answer. I already tried this, got an error: Error occurred while importing students: 'windows-1250' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. (Parameter 'name'). I tried it with capital W, small w, apparently GetEncoding() does not recognize Windows-1250 encoding. (-1 is not me)

Is it installed on your machine?

Well, I guess you might not even be on Windows nowadays with .NET Core. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix I know it says 1252, but the same goes fro 1250.

I tried this, this is my code:
`Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1252)))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
                {

...`
Does not work
